# Data sets generation in R

Tags: r

I want to generate two data set for further calculation. The two sets are almost same except for one parameter. I would like to know is that possible to use loop to do this kind of automation in R. Thank you!

```
classes   <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

#this is parameter I would like to use to generate 2 different data set
n_1        <- 25
n_2        <- 50 

#This is data set I would like to get 
dataset_1 <- rep(classes, 25) 
dataset_2 <- rep(classes, 50)
```

If I use n_pool as substitution for n_1  and n_2

```
n_pool         <- c(25,50)

#For loop has something wrong
for (a in n_pool) {
  dataset_[a] <- rep(classes, a)
}
```

I know the 'dataset_[a]' MUST be wrong, but I would like to know:

Is it possible that I write a loop in R to automate this process in avoid of any useless repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close actually, you just need to use `assign` and `paste0` like this:

```r
classes   <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

#this is parameter I would like to use to generate 2 different data set
n_1        <- 25
n_2        <- 50 

#This is data set I would like to get 
dataset_1 <- rep(classes, 25) 
dataset_2 <- rep(classes, 50) 

n_pool         <- c(25,50)

#For loop has something wrong
for (a in n_pool) {
  assign(paste0('dataset_', a), rep(classes, a))
}

identical(dataset_1, dataset_25)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(dataset_2, dataset_50)
#> [1] TRUE

## or
for (i in 1:2) {
  assign(paste0('dataset_', i), rep(classes, get(paste0('n_', i))))
}
identical(dataset_1, dataset_25)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(dataset_2, dataset_50)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think `lapply` is better than `for-loop`.

```
n_list <- list(n_1 = 25, n_2 = 50)

data_list <- lapply(n_list, function(x) rep(classes, x))
```

You can then access data by names, such as `data_list$n_1`.

Comment: One thing is that I will use n_1 and n_2 separately later in my code. So I still need to write extra code ...

Comment: @Steve Still better than use `for-loop` to create separate objects in your workspace, at least this is what I think. Too many objects in the workspace are difficult to manage.

Comment: I agree. At least in R, if I can use functions, it is better not to use loops. I will think about the solution you suggested. Thank you!